# Maven WAR file directory structure is incorrect - Teamcity

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, continuous-integration, teamcity

The war file created by Teamcity Maven build isn't correct. There are duplicate web.xml and all root files are under classes. I'm new to maven and teamcity. Can someone point out what went wrong here?

Here is the war file structure:

```
[root@hostname ~]# unzip LoginDemo-1.0.0.17.war -d LoginDemo-1.0.0.17
[root@hostname ~]# tree LoginDemo-1.0.0.17
LoginDemo-1.0.0.17
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── LoginDemo
│           └── LoginDemo
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── error.html
    │   ├── login.html
    │   ├── logout.jsp
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
    │   ├── securePage1.jsp
    │   ├── securePage2.jsp
    │   └── WEB-INF
    │       └── web.xml
    └── web.xml
```

My Source directory structure is

```
[root@hostname src]# tree /opt/teamcity/work/a1335cb631475bf4/src/main/webapp/
/opt/teamcity/work/a1335cb631475bf4/src/main/webapp/
├── error.html
├── login.html
├── logout.jsp
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── securePage1.jsp
├── securePage2.jsp
└── WEB-INF
    └── web.xml
```

My Teamcity Build configuration looks like this.

General Settings:

[image: Teamcity General settings]

Build Steps:

[image: Teamcity Build steps]

Pom.xml looks like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>LoginDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>LoginDemo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.17</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Login Demo</name>
  <description>Login Demo Java Project</description>
  <build>
        <resources>
                <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                </resource>
          </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. `warSourceDirectory` should have been `src/main/webapp` and then I also  deleted  the `resources` (I think its for other external stuff that needs to be included). Now the War file structure is correct.

Here is the updated POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>LoginDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>LoginDemo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.17</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Login Demo</name>
  <description>Login Demo Java Project</description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```